# Return a value of 0 or 0.00 if data field is not found in table - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I seem to be in a pinch here... What I'm doing right now is doing computations in one select statement query. Problem is... some ID's are not found in another table but they are found in the table I declare which is **gndtndr**. The ID's that are not found on another table is **gndsale**.  What I want to do is that when the ID's are not found on **gndsale**... I would just declare it as value of 0 or 0.00 and put it as a column name **DECLARED**.

I tried the query what's on my mind but its not working :c 
Can you help me on this?

The error that is showing is: **Subquery returns more than 1 row**

Here's my query:

```
SELECT g.ID , concat(emp.FIRSTNAME, ' ', emp.LASTNAME) Fullname,

(CASE 
 when (select DISTINCT ID from gndtndr where ID NOT IN (select 
ID from gndsale)) then '0'
else 
FORMAT(ROUND(SUM(s.AMOUNT), 2),0)
END) as DECLARED,

FORMAT(ROUND(SUM(G.amount), 2),0) as CALCULATED,

FORMAT(ROUND(SUM(G.amount), 2) - ROUND(SUM(S.AMOUNT),2),0) AS `CASH SHORT` 
FROM gndtndr g JOIN emp ON emp.ID = g.ID JOIN gndsale s on 
g.ID=S.ID JOIN adjtime a on a.ID = g.ID group by 
ID
```

Below is a sample data and my expected result

**GNDSALE TABLE**

[image: gndsale table]

**GNDTNDR TABLE**

[image: gndtndr table]

**Expected result**

[image: expected result]

Comment: Give sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join with the table 'gndsale' and then in case statement check for the id is null in that case return 0.
"case when gndsale.id is null then 0 end"
I think this will solve your problem

Comment: WOAH IT WORKED! :D I got my expected result :)

Comment: Here's my code :) 
    (CASE when s.EMPLOYEE IS NULL then '0' when s.EMPLOYEE IS 
   NOT NULL then FORMAT(ROUND(SUM(s.AMOUNT), 2),0) END) as 
   DECLARED